# going back to onCreate

Tags: android

I want my code to be readable so i'm writing different methods that do whatever they do and go back to onCreate which calls the next one to be executed. one of my methods has an onAnimationEnd listener, I want the onCreate method to wait for the animation to end and then call the next method, how can I do that without calling the next method from the listener itself?

Thanks in advance

```
onCreate() 
{
 doTask1();
 doTask2();
}

private void doTask1(){
    ...
    ...
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            // finish this method and let onCreate call the next one
        }
}
```

Comment: 'I want the onCreate method to wait for'- the UI-thread related methods should never "wait"

Comment: what about calling `onAnimationEnd()` in `doInBackground` of [`AsyncTask`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=android+asynctask&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fos%2FAsyncTask.html&ei=Vt0sUeCsHYPsrAfIsoGgAw&usg=AFQjCNE8gLVXz1Hwq4rI8oxRkZNHjhRzpQ&bvm=bv.42965579,d.bmk)?

Comment: @user1281750 its not exactly "waiting", the animation is really short and i dont want anything to happen on the screen before if is finished...

Comment: Not possible Androidz

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, you should implement something like:

```
onCreate() 
{
 doTask1();
 doTask2();
}

private void doTask1(){
    Animation animation;
    ...
    ...
    onAnimationEnd(animation);
}

public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) { 
        ...
}
```

If the onAnimationEnd method is a listener, I advert you implemente something like:

```
onCreate()  { 
    addActions(); //you can choose which method call first
    doTask1();
    doTask2();
}

private void addActions(){
    ...
    ...
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            // finish this method and let onCreate call the next one
        } 
}

private void doTask1(){
    ...
}
```